# BottomNavigationView shows black strips

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I created an app and I tested it many times in android emulators.

I created a `BottomNavigationView` which looks as follow in multiple phones I tested:

[image]

However, when I run it on other devices it looks as follows with these black lines above and under the `BottomNavigationView`:

[image]

The devices I tried them on are Samsung and Xiaomi. I just want to mention that on some devices it works well and on some not. Seems like on large phones it makes it.

The xml code is:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/btm_nav"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/btm_nav"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.08"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_btm_nav" />
```

The Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/MenuNav_Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_general_home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_search"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/MenuNav_Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/MenuNav_Profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_general_profile"/>
</menu>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/colorLightPurple" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/colorGray"  />
</selector>
```

Any ideas why these black lines appear?

Also when I increased the padding it increased the black line in the emulator but even with 0dp it shows the line.

Thank you

Tried to use the following edits:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/btm_nav_background"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorLightPurple"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorLightPurple"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.08"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_btm_nav" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorWhite" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorWhite" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

However, it was the same.

SOLUTION:

adding `android:background="@color/colorWhite"` solved the problem...

Comment: There are some issues: `itemBackground` should be a drawable. `itemIconTint` and `itemTextColor` should be colors.

Comment: Tried to change but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

`android:color` only provides a hex color that can't be recognized as a Drawable, while `app:itembackground` requires a Drawable

change `app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"` to `app:itemBackground="@drawable/btm_nav_background"`

btm_nav_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/banner_white" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/banner_black" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: from my understanding, it will change the color of the bottons when they are clicked, not the top and bottom of the whole navigationbar no? If I do go with this method, any way to declare inside drawable only a color?

Comment: @Ben yes, it just changes the selected item. not the whole navigation bottom

Comment: But I cant just make @drawable/white right? It means I need to create the whole icon in other color?

Comment: yeah, no difference. did you try to test it without `app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"`?

Comment: Yes, It made it look like purple/grey squares without seeing the icons